# Why does assinging a value to the key `True` of an dictionary overwrite the value of the key `1` in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, hashtable, hash-collision

For this simple Dictionary -

the Key 1 and Value "apple" always print as "1: False"

is there a reason for this I've overlooked?

**$ cat dict.py**

```
pairs = {1: "apple",
    "orange": [2, 3, 4], 
    True: False, 
    None: "True",
}
print(pairs)
```

***$ python3.8 dict.py**

```
{1: False, 'orange': [2, 3, 4], None: 'True'}
```

thanks

Comment: True/False are special cases of integers1/0- but they are different kind of class (boolean). Seems like a bug to me - Intuitively I would not want to overwrite my interger 1 key by True:False. Its the same in 3.7

Comment: Same for `p = {}, p[1] = "apple", p[True] = False, print(p)`= will overwrite the `apple` with `False`

Comment: `hash(1) == hash(True)` but I agree the behaviour is not intuitive.

Comment: and in Python v2.7.13 as well - seems to be an accepted thing. One more oddity to remember - but I would probably never use True and ints together as keys in a dict anyhow ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been practising and - want to understand how everything works and why - as I'm sure you can understand --- will note this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bool` type in Python is a subtype of `int` where `True` equals the number `1` and `False` equals the number `0`:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

When the values are hashed, they also result in the respectively same value:

```
>>> hash(True)
1
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash(False)
0
>>> hash(0)
0
```

Now, since dictionary keys are based on hash and object equality (hash equality is used first to find possibly equal keys fast, and then they are compared through equality), two values that result in the same hash and are equal will result in the same “slot” of the dictionary.

You can also see this if you create a custom type that also has this behavior:

```
>>> class CustomTrue:
        def __hash__(self):
            return 1
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return other == 1

>>> pairs = {
        1: "apple",
        "orange": [2, 3, 4], 
        True: False, 
        None: "True",
    }
>>> pairs[CustomTrue()] = 'CustomTrue overwrites the value'
>>> pairs
{1: 'CustomTrue overwrites the value', 'orange': [2, 3, 4], None: 'True'}
```

While this explains the behavior, I do agree that it can be somewhat confusing. As such I would recommend not to use dictionary keys of different types so that you don’t run into such a situation.

Comment: That's a true in-dept answer I will be taking this to play with further- I applaud you and thank you.

Comment: @JakeCope Glad I could help! If this solved your question, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) to mark the question as resolved.